# How to iterate on two arrays and produce unique y coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Context: In Sketch, I am writing a plugin to render text on the canvas that shows a vertical list of text and its font size + weight combinations.

[ Uses JavaSCript [

The problem: I cannot figure out how to programmatically increase the Y pos of each layer properly.

Say I have two arrays:

```js
const fontWeights = ['normal', 'bold'];
const fontSizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
```

I want to generate a vertical list of each combination of fontWeight + fontSize, so it looks like this:

```js
smallNormal
smallBold
mediumNormal
mediumBold
largeNormal
largeBold
```

(or graphically, [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrNb7.png))

```js
function renderLayers() {
   return fontWeights.map((weight, weightsIndex) => 
       fontSizes.map((size, sizeIndex) => 
           return (
               <TextLayer 
                   fontSize={size} 
                   fontWeight={weight} 
                   yPos={ (weightsIndex + sizeIndex) * 100 } 
               />
}
```

That kinda works, except there is a case where:

```
0 + 0 * 100 = 0
0 + 1 * 100 = 100
1 + 0 * 100 = 100 // <-- that should be 200
```

All I really want to do is offset each iteration by a fixed amount. I am sure that there's some logic / mathematical way to do this, but i am stuck.

Help would be great thanks!

Comment: IMO Even if the above works, it is unreadable. I'd much rather have an external variable.

Comment: (weightsIndex*fontSize.length+sizeIndex)*100. outer loop index * inner loop length gives you how many you got after finishing 1 round of inner loop iteration.

Comment: @LuísRamalho Just trying to solve it in a logic/math way. I'm not sure why adding a fontSize.length makes it unreadable.

Comment: I understand, my comment was more along the lines of if I was looking at `(weightsIndex*fontSize.length+sizeIndex)*100` I would have absolutely no idea that it was just adding `100` with each iteration of a map nested in another. So, even though it works and it's clever, it's very hard to read, whereas if you simply have another variable that you can clearly see it's being incremented `y = y + 100` in the most inner map, then it's pretty clear :) -- there's nothing wrong with your approach, I didn't mean it that way. It's just maybe too clever and it would take a couple minutes to understand.

Comment: Totally understand.  a variable to sum up offset is a good approach and clear in most cases. Up vote for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep an external variable to store the yPos:

```
function renderLayers() {
  let y = 0;
  return fontWeights.map((weight) =>
    fontSizes.map((size) => {
      y = y + 100;
      return <TextLayer fontSize={size} fontWeight={weight} yPos={y} />;
    })
  );
}
```

The map index might not be the best for this job because it alternates between 0 and the length of the array - 1, so it's really not what you want. You need some variable on the outside of the maps that can store the "count" of both iterations combined.

I've added a new line, but you could also just do:

```
return <TextLayer fontSize={size} fontWeight={weight} yPos={y += 100} />;
```

Comment: Would this also work the same if I had more nested arrays? For instance I also have two font families as well as alignments, so the number of arrays to map over goes up

Comment: Sure! https://github.com/lucastobrazil/sketch-generate-palette/blob/master/src/text-styles/index.js